# overflowing navbar in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experimenting with Bootstrap 3.2. I'm trying to create a fixed at top navigation bar but I'm running into two problems:

1. The navigation bar overlaps the content below it.
2. The navigation bar seems to be going far off the screen to the right. This makes my button in the navigation bar not visible unless the window width is dragged to a smaller size.

For the first problem, I've followed the [Bootstrap example tip](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) by adding a class to my css file, including this file below the Bootstrap css file in the html document, and then referring to the class.

```
.navbar-height{
    body{padding-top: 200px;}
}

<body class="navbar-height">
```

Though, this seems to do nothing (as you can see I specified the number really high hoping to see a dramatic change, which did not occur).

Here's my the navigation bar:

```
<header id="header-navigation">
        <div id="nav-bar-container">
            <nav id="nav-bar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div id="nav-item-container" class="container-fluid">
                    <div id="drop-down" class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-dropdown">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="home-button" class="navbar-left">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="Brand" src=""></img></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="user-dropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-items" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <div class="list-group-item">
                                    <div class="row-picture">
                                        <img class="circle" src="" alt="icon"></img>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row-content">
                                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Placeholder</h4>
                                        <p class="list-group-item-text">Placeholder</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="list-group-seperator"></div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
</header>
```

As a quick break down of the above code, I have a `<header>` tag which will hold the navigation bar. Within this `<header>`, I have a containing `<div>` (id="nav-bar-container") which only purpose is to act as a container for the navigation bar (maybe I'll add something else to the header and want to keep the bar seperate). Then, I have the actual `<nav>` which has the appropriate classes (or so I think): "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top". The next `<div>` (id="nav-item-container") holds the components of the navigation bar. The following `<div>` (id="drop-down") contains the button (which seems to disappear at full-screen) and a link with a "brand", which always seems to be visible. The last major `<div>` contains the "drop down" content for when the button is pressed.

**My Question:** why is my navigation bar overlapping the content below it and over extending to the right hiding the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for problem number two, where I believed the navigation bar to be overflowing off the screen to the right, was just a mistake in the layout of the code. I was grouping the button I wanted to display on the right with the brand in the "navbar-header". What this does is display the brand but use that button only on a mobile screen to hide or show its associated dropdown. That is why I was only seeing the button when I made the width smaller by dragging the window. To fix this problem I removed the button and placed it within the appropriate code block. So, my "navbar-header" now looks like this:

```
<div id="drop-down" class="navbar-header">
    <div id="home-button" class="navbar-left">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="Brand" src=""></img></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, next within the id="nav-item-container" parent `div`, I create a list of items (`ul`). This list contains the items within the navigation bar and has the classes "nav navbar-nav navbar-right". Each list item (`li`) within this list is an item within the navigation bar. Dropdown buttons and their contents must be contained within the same list item (`li`). Make sure the parenting list item to the dropdown elements contains the class "dropdown". Then, the button or link should have the "dropdown-toggle" class applied to it. And the dropdown items themselves (which too can be a list of items and often is) should have the class "dropdown-menu". For example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
    </a>
    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-items" role="menu">
      <li>
     <div class="list-group-item">
       <div class="row-picture">
      <img class="circle" src="" alt="icon"></img>
       </div>
       <div class="row-content">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Placeholder</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">Placeholder</p>
       </div>
       <div class="list-group-seperator"></div>
     </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
    </ul> 

  </li>
</ul>
```

Note, in the snippet I didn't include the parenting nav, div, or header so it may not work exactly how it should. Also, I figured the majority of this out on my own by referencing [the Bootstrap component page,](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) as well as, [the Bootstrap material design page](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) (a plugin to Bootstrap that gives everything the Google Material Design look and feel). So, I'm not sure if all the "rules" I stated are mandatory or if there are other ways to achieve this.

As for problem number one, I just made a silly mistake with the css and the two other answers provided correct ways of fixing it. All I had to do was fix the body css like so:

```
body{
    padding-top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, first thing, you don't need the `<header>` tag, so feel free to remove that.

Second, from the Docs on `navbar-fixed-top`, you need to have padding:

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

Notice you applied it to the heading style; that won't work. Apply it to the body and it works fine.

As far as the 2nd issue, I don't actually see any horizontal scrolling when I removed the
`<header>` tag, so I think that may have been causing an issue.

Checkout this Bootply example:

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/OnZ1j8oULN)

To see what I mean. It's your code with the tag removed. Hope that helps!

Comment: The hilarious part is that the Bootply header overflows its content.

Answer (score 2):

Change..

```
.navbar-height{
    body{padding-top: 200px;}
}
```

to..

```
body.navbar-height{
    padding-top: 200px;
}
```

You want the padding on the body itself.  This will push you body down 200px giving you a gutter at the top for your fixed navbar.

most likely you'd want to adjust this padding depending on the actual height of your navbar.